# trigger ajax call as soon as div get loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

I really need your help.
I wanted to trigger ajax as soon as div get loaded. I added using onLoad attribute to the div tag but it dint work for me.I dont want to use onLoad in the body of the HTML only it should get load in the div itself.Please help.

```
<div class="contentDiv" onload="function();">
```

Comment: are you adding this div later dynamically..?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
$('.contentDiv').load(function() {
      //YOUR AJAX CALL
});
```

OR

```
 $(document).on('load','.contentDiv', function() {
      //YOUR AJAX CALL  
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.contentDiv').load(function(){
        // ajax here

     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The onload event can only be used on the document(body) itself, frames, images, and scripts. In other words, it can be attached to only body and/or each external resource. The div is not an external resource and it's loaded as part of the body

So the easy way you could do here is to put the script dirctly after you div

```
<div>
</div>
<script>
//your code for action goes here
</script>
```

Comment: But adding script next to the div is not a good way of coding right??? any other alternatives??

Comment: It depends on the circumstances. Here i think it will be better for you. It will not make any more complications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for loading an AJAX content dynamically as soon as the div is visible (scroll down) then take a look at http://jscroll.com/